# Read image from cache for app ios with swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm currently reading images from my firebase storage - which works fine.

I have set up a caching to read images from the cache when it has been read from the storage:

```
    // Storage.imageCache.object(forKey: post.imageUrl as NSString)
static func getImage(with url: String, completionHandler: @escaping (UIImage) -> ())
{
    if let image = imageCache.object(forKey: url as NSString)
    {
        print("CACHE: Unable to read image from CACHE ")

        completionHandler(image)
    }
    else
    {
        let ref = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: url)
        ref.data(withMaxSize: 2 * 1024 * 1024)
        {
            (data, error) in

            if let error = error
            {
                print("STORAGE: Unable to read image from storage \(error)")
            }
            else if let data = data
            {
                print("STORAGE: Image read from storage")
                if let image = UIImage(data: data)
                {
                    // Caches the image
                    Storage.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: url as NSString)
                    completionHandler(image)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

But its not working. It seems to not work at all as well, I don't have the message '            print("CACHE: Unable to read image from CACHE ")
' being displayed on my console but the print '                 print("STORAGE: Image read from storage")
'

Do you know how this can be achieved by any chance please?

Thanks a lot for your time!

---EDIT --

I call the image in table cell view from firebase storage then as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
    let cell = self.feedTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell")! as UITableViewCell

    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    let titleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    let linkLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel

    titleLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    linkLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].link
    linkLabel.numberOfLines = 0



    Storage.getImage(with: posts[indexPath.row].imageUrl){
        postPic in
        imageView.image = postPic
    }

    return cell

}
```

Comment: This Library is great for downloading images from internet (I use them with firebase as well), you can have progress, Completion Handler, Placeholder image and great cache loading: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can realize caching images with Kingfisher for example. And works better. [link](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

How to use: Add link to your image from storage to database item node. Like this:

[image]

Then just use it to present and cache image.

Example:

```
 let imageView = UIImageView(frame: frame) // init with frame for example
 imageView.kf.setImage(with: <urlForYourImageFromFireBase>) //Using kf for caching images
```

Hope it helps